# How to pass dynamic variable through class function

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass every value through the function (it's a part of cms) so later on user can view content and then when he confirms it is saved to database and a separate file is made that looks exactly as preview but I don't know and have no idea how to pass a dynamic variable like $_POST['champno'.$i] right below

```
public function display($patch, $champ_number){

                    echo '<h1 style="float: left;">PATCH ';
                    echo $patch.'</h1>
                            <nav id="header-menu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">PATCHES</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">CHAMPIONS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">ITEMS</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">CHANGES</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                            <div id="title">
                                <h2>CHAMPION BALANCE CHANGES</h2>
                            </div>';
                    for($i=1;$i<=$champ_number; $i++){
                        ?>
                        <style type="text/css" scoped>
                            @media(min-width: 640px){
                                .<?php echo $_POST['champno'.$i]; ?>{
                                background-image: url('../../assets/champions/<?php echo $_POST['champno'.$i]; ?>_pc.jpg');
```

Comment: I don't understand a single part of the question.

Comment: there is variable $_POST['champno'.$i] which I'm trying to pass like I did with $patch and $champ_number

Comment: Since `$_POST` is a superglobal it is always in scope. You therefore don't need to pass it and your code should already work.

Comment: What isn't working? If `$_POST['champno1']` etc., is defined this will work fine?

Comment: this code works fine, but i'm trying to change it because later on I'll be passing this data from database so it won't be $_POST['champno'.$i] anymore

Answer (score 0):

Extract the information from `$_POST['champno'.$i]` into a dedicated array and call the function with that:

```
$champions = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $champ_number; $i++)
    $champions[] = $_POST['champno' . $i];
$obj->display($patch, $champions);
```

In the function:

```
function display($patch, $champions) {
    ...
    foreach ($champions as $champion) {
        $champion = htmlspecialchars($champion);
        ?>
        <style type="text/css" scoped>
            @media(min-width: 640px) {
                .<?php echo $champion; ?> {
                    background-image: url('../../assets/champions/<?php echo $champion; ?>_pc.jpg');
        ...
        <?php
    }
}
```

Then you can use the function with the database and all other input sources.